# Chrome - save password on this site offer

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser

I created html form for registration, where user must fill password input.
Actually if "register" button is pressed, then i process form on the server side and i make redirect. Chrome still offering me if i want to save password on this site (probably because it knows that there is password input on tha form, which was submitted). I wanna dissalow this offer from browser when user is registering.

Comment: This answer helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27072657/192221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `autocomplete="off"` on your input:

```
<input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion