# Google chrome incorrectly saving username

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

First I am not trying to circumvent the browsers auto complete functionality. Happy for auto complete to save and populate a password.

My form contains 3 inputs

- Quantity
- Phone number (optional)
- Password

Currently on submission the quantity or phone number gets saved as the username. Ideally I would save the users email address. However this is not part of the form and I do not wish it to be visible but I can populate it from the server.

How do I go about doing this?

Also happy if chrome just saves the password with no associated username if thats a thing?

Things Ive tried:

- Created a hidden input element before the password containing an email address. - No luck
- Created a hidden empty password input element before the real password input. - No luck ([Prevent Chrome from prompting to save password from input box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280461/prevent-chrome-from-prompting-to-save-password-from-input-box))

Created a hidden empty password input element before the real password input. - No luck

Comment: Why not just have a standard input field with their email address?

Comment: I dont require the user to re-auth and do not want an additional input field for a user to navigate. However I do want the protection of the password input to prevent accidental transactions (Autocomplete being something a user may choose to disable within the browser).

Comment: Did you try checking the `name=""` if they are different?

Comment: Yup all inputs have different names. Im pretty sure Chrome just looks for the input closest to the password field that contains a value and uses that for the username (but I could have this wrong?). Quantity is sometimes being used because the phone number is optional.

Comment: If the user is already authenticated, then you don't want chrome to be saving a password.  Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280461/prevent-chrome-from-prompting-to-save-password-from-input-box)

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works. I had tried the hidden input field already(containing the email address with name and id as "username"). I have now just tried the empty email address solution but again chrome has gotten smarter.