# Disabling browser password saving in my Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, web, browser, devextreme

I'm creating an Angular application with Devextreme components. The question is that I don't want that in my Login screen when I enter the username and password the browser suggests me to save the password:
[image]

I would like to know if from my angular application there is a way to make this not happen and that this solution will work for some of the browsers. I would also like to know a solution to prevent the password fields from suggesting passwords as shown below:

[image]

At the moment I have tried adding the following parameters to my text components:

```
autocomplete="off"
autocomplete="new-password"
autocomplete="chrome-off"
```

The autocomplete="new-password" option works fine for me so that it does not autocomplete the fields when I have the password saved in the browser. But it still suggests me what I have shown in the two images above.

I hope someone can help. Thank you very much!

Comment: I would agree with this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244490/616535 that it is not a really good practice to try to prevent a browser on HTML/JavaScript level from prompting to save a password. If you're really need it probably there is a way to disable it on browser level settings.

Comment: Please have a look at this as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775342/how-to-disable-chromes-saved-password-prompt-setting-through-javascript   and the this to check which browsers are supported   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can use autocomplete="one-time-code" to prevent password save prompts. It suggests autocompletion for single-use codes.

Refs:

- [Stack Overflow: Chrome password prompt prevention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27280461/prevent-chrome-from-prompting-to-save-password-from-input-box/35244490#35244490)
- [Methods to disable Chrome autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)
- [HTML autocomplete attribute guide](https://robindirksen.com/blog/html-autocomplete-one-time-code)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Devextreme components like DxTextBox, this will resolve the issue:

```
<dx-text-box ...
    [inputAttr]="{ autocomplete: 'new-password' }">
</dx-text-box>
```

if using in DxForm:

```
<dx-form ...>
    <dxi-item ... editorType="dxTextBox" [editorOptions]="{inputAttr: {autocomplete: 'new-password'}}"></dxi-item>
</dx-form>
```

NOTE: the Chrome team now requires that each input should have a valid autocomplete attribute value. That's why the "chrome-off" and "none" values stopped working.