# How to restrict browser saved id and password of login form are set by browser in another form after login?

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication

If user name and password of login form are saved by browser. Then this user name and password are set by browser in another form of dashboard after login. But I does not wants to set the user name and password of login into this dashboard form. How to prevent the browser to set these user name and password in insider dashboard form but I want that browser save these only for login form.

Answer (score 0):

#### Chrome (not supported)

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177225/how-do-i-disable-the-save-password-bubble-in-chrome-using-javascript)

#### Others

> The easiest and simplest way to disable Form and Password storage
>   prompts and prevent form data from being cached in session history is
>   to use the autocomplete form element attribute with value "off".
>
> From http://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32386/2246862)

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: No this does not work in chrome. I have written autocomplete="off" but chrome gives password storage prompts.

Comment: doesn't seem to be supported natively by chrome. I added another post with the same question about chrome