# stop remember me popup in chrome using java-script

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extension, browser-security

i want to stop popup remember me box in asp mvc (programmatically) i tried autocomplete=off place password text-box and set it hidden but no solution is working.

Tried

```
autocomplete="off"
```

Tried

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" />
```

Tried

```
<form id="loginForm" action="login.cgi" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Tried

```
<input style="display:none">
<input type="password" style="display:none">
```

**None of this working please guide me**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality)

Comment: no i tried this its not working popup is still showing @Alex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable the save password bubble in chrome using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177225/how-do-i-disable-the-save-password-bubble-in-chrome-using-javascript)