# Stop Chrome offering to save the contents of an input as the users password

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, autofill

I've got a web application that uses a two page authentication process:

1. Capture the username and password from the user (`login.x.com/#/login`)
2. Capture three characters from the users "memorable word" (`login.x.com/#/login/memorable`)

   1. Submit the details to the server via the AngularJS $http service (POST)
   2. Process the response and either continue to step 3, or repeat step 2
3. Redirect user to their home page (`app.x.com/#/dashboard`)

The second step currently consists of three single character text fields (`<input type="password" maxlength="1" size="1" ...... />`) where the user is prompted to enter characters *m*, *n* and *o* from their memorable word.

The problem lies between steps 2 and 3; currently Chrome prompts the user to update their password for the site, with one of the single characters they've entered from their memorable word. I have no desire to stop the user storing their password, but I would like to work out how to stop Chrome from attempting to *update* their password with one of the characters from their memorable word.

Things that I've tried, without success:

- Setting `autocomplete="off"` on the memorable word character inputs
- Setting `autocomplete="new-password"` on the memorable word character inputs
- Setting `autocomplete="memorable-word-character"` on the memorable word character inputs. This isn't a "well known" autocomplete "type" but was tried on an "it can't hurt and is worth a go" basis
- `<input type="password" style="display:none"/>` as suggested in answers to some other questions

I'd prefer *not* to change the UI significantly, e.g. Changing the input type so it's no longer `password`, or changing the text fields to drop-downs. The latter is because we currently permit any character, other than a space, to be used in the memorable word so it's not really viable.

Is there a standard and accepted way to tell Chrome (and other browsers) that these fields are not the users password field?

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949954/4209853) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32775859/4209853)?

Comment: @xDaizu, unfortunately neither of those worked - I guess they've been locked down over time by Chrome in their ongoing efforts to stop developers disabling autofill/save for passwords; which I absolutely agree with - when it's actually a password field!!