# How can I prevent Chrome from incorrectly grabbing a username and password and trying to store it into the user's password manager?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Chrome is attempting to store a username and password after a user submits my password reset form, logs out, and then goes back to the main login page.

[image]
In this case it seems to grabbing information where userid and password are being sent to an endpoint. My best guess is that it thinks because one of the fields was called password, and one before it was probably the username (however that's not the case here).

My preferred outcome would be this still pops up but uses the correct fields. Alternatively, if I need to I'd like to prevent this from happening all together (without asking the user to disable it in their chrome browser) Or maybe find a way to feed Chrome the username?

I've tried putting autocomplete="off" and autocomplete="new-password" on the form fields themselves, but this has had no effect.

I'm using a ApolloGraphQL to send the userId and password to the back-end. There are actually no fields named "password" though there are fields named "newPassword" and "retypedPassword" and "currentPassword"

Comment: once you turned off the auto complete. Have you tried the hard refresh(ctrl + F5)  or incognito window to check the effect. Kindly confirm

Comment: - still happens with (ctrl + f5 refresh)
- does not happen in incognito mode

Comment: Issue has been resolved by following this suggestion, it did not disable the bubble, but actually fixed it and made it work properly, which I was not expecting:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949954/2600246