# Remove Password saving from browser

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

How to remove password saving popup in browser when login in C#,jQuery or JavaScript.
I am using autocomplete property but not effective use that
any other option available..?

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: any other tricky methods available..?

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177225/how-do-i-disable-the-save-password-bubble-in-chrome-using-javascript